# Laravel Eloquent how to get all products in a category with slug

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My Productcategory.php has

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

And Product.php has

```
public function productcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Productcategory', 'category_id');
}
```

Now my route is

```
Route::get('gallery/{slug}', 'GalleryController@index');
```

When URL is something like `gallery/print-pattern-client-work`, how can I get all products with the same category? I have the following but `category_id` is an integer and not a slug. So I am not so sure how to do it.

```
public function index()
{
    $categoryslug = Request::segment(2);
    $products = Productcategory::with('products')->where('category_id',$categoryslug)->get();
...
}
```

Comment: `print-pattern-client-work` is it any category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes you have a column named "slug" in your product_categories table. And that your described relations work well.

You could make an accessor in Product.php

```
public function scopeFindByCategorySlug($query, $categorySlug)
{
    return $query->whereHas('productcategory', function ($query) use ($categorySlug) {
        $query->where('slug', $categorySlug);
    });
}
```

Then in your controller you call this:

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $products = Product::findByCategorySlug($slug)->get();
}
```

Edit:

As mentioned in comments there is no actual need for an accessor. This is basically all you need (in controller):

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $products = Product::whereHas('productcategory', function ($query) use ($categorySlug) {
        $query->where('slug', $categorySlug);
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: He could also do the `whereHas` directly in the `index` method, but your answer is indeed the only correct one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.   $products = Product::whereHas('productcategory', function ($query) use ($slug) {
            $query->where('slug', $slug);
        })->get();

Answer (score 2):

Don't

```
$categoryslug = Request::segment(2);
```

Use `$slug`

```
public function index($slug)
{
    $products = Productcategory::with('products')->where('category_id',$slug)->get();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Laravel, you should use Laravel's [Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) like this:

Your table structure would be like:

```
- products
    - id
    - name
    - ...

- categories
    - id
    - name
    - slug
    - ...

- category_product
    - id
    - category_id
    - product_id
    - ...
```

Your models should be like this:

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function categories() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product');
    }

}

class Category extends Model {

    public function products() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_product');
    }

}
```

and you can fetch all the products for a particular `$category_slug` like this:

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();
if($category) {
    $products = $category->products;
}
```